# Install MongoDB on Debian 8.0 (Jessie)

Tags: mongodb, debian

I can't install mongodb on debian 8.

I use the instruction on [docs.mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/#run-mongodb-community-edition)

When i run `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`, getting error:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My source.list

```
sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* 
deb http://fastpanel.fastvps.ru/fastpanel wheezy main
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 main
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ wheezy nginx
```

Comment: try with `--fix-missing` option. i.e `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org --fix-missing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mixed sources.list jessie and wheezy , keep only  `mongodb-org-3.4.list` under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` with the following url :

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 main
```

Also , verify your `/etc/apt/sources.list` you should have only the URLs compatible with debian jessie.

Then run :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

Comment: Thank you. there really was a problem with the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `--fix-missing` option.

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org --fix-missing
```

Comment: @Barmaley Are you sure you followed the official documentation step by step. Are you sure you Updated the package list after adding to the `sources.list.d`

Comment: If so try `sudo apt-get autoclean` to clean partial package and then try `sudo apt-get clean` to clean `apt-cache`. Also try `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean unmet dependencies. Finally, try `reinstalling`. This may help you.